# How do I use the standard Xcode GUI on top of C++ code

Tags: c++, macos, user-interface, ide

I have a book that teaches physics for game developers.  The code is generic C-style code.  However, the examples use GUI's to interface with the code (variable initialization, start conditions, etc...). The GUI code is not implemented and is left to the reader.  Ideally, at home on my MAC, I would like to use the GUI builder in Xcode to build these little interfaces and then use the GUI to run the code.  However, I don't want to code the physics code in Swift or Objective-C, I just want to code it in C++ so that I can transfer the code to work (which is Windows and uses Visual Studios).  If someone could just point me in the direction of a resource that explains how to have a MAC GUi call C++ code and do this all in Xcode, that would be great.

I have done some searches but I don't think I am a using the correct terminology to get the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

This is very broad.

General principles would be to have the physics code in its own set of portable C++ files. Regular C++ and headers. Basic structures exposed, maybe expose std:: containers but keep it generic.

Beside that, use the UI builder in xcode, but only ever refer to the physics code in code you write. This will look like:

nice_physics.cpp

```
// portable code here
```

nice_physics.h

```
class NicePhysic
{
  public:
    int nice_function(float);
};
```

brandname_ui.cpp

```
// hook generated by your IDE
UGLY_DECL_TYPE UGLY_MACRO valueChanged(UGLY_TYPE i)
{
    NicePhysic phys; // move this object to wherever the UI system you use allows it
    // make whatever calls you need to your physics system
    phys.nice_function(0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Objective C++ is your answer. If you name your files with a .mm extension, you can use mix and match C++ features with Objective C features. You'll have two object systems running side by side. You can't derive C++ classes from Objective C classes and vice versa, but that's about the only major limitation. C++ code can construct ObjC objects and send ObjC messages, ObjC methods can instantiate and call C++ objects.